# React how to access state from a function in another file?

Tags: reactjs

I have the component `Login`:

```
class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isAuthenticated: false
        };
```

and want to access `isAuthenticated` from another file `routes.js`:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => (
        Login.state.isAuthenticated === true
        ? <Component {...this.props}/>
        : <Redirect to="/" />
    )}/> 
)


export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
);
```

How would I go about doing this? Also what is this routes file called? Is it another "component"? Would I need to somehow pass the state from `Login` as `props`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gist of it is that parent component must have state as a parent cannot touch a child's state. There are several ways to achieve what you're trying to do:

1. Have the parent contain the state and just pass a function to `Login` to have controlled access to the parent state
2. Have `Login` render `PrivateRoute` conditionally
3. Use Context API or some state management tool like redux so that the state is effectively global

---

Some suggestions for 1:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { isAuthenticated: false }
  }

  setAuthenticated = (isAuthenticated) => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={() =>
                  <Login
                    isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated} 
                    setAuthenticated={this.setAuthenticated}/>}/>
                <Route path="/register" exact component={Register} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" exact component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>)
  }
}
```

And then `Login` would need to be altered to pull the value of `isAuthenticated` and use the function `setAuthenticated` from the props.

Comment: How would I do number 1? Who's the parent here?

Comment: Updated to give you some suggestions for 1 :)

Comment: I'm still a little confused. How is the `isAuthenticated` inside `<Login .../>` of the `App` class in sync with the `isAuthenticated` in the state of `Login` class?

Comment: It's not. `Login` would need to get the prop `isAuthenticated` which is set based on the state of the `App`. Whenever the state in `App` is changed, `App` will re-render `Login` with the updated prop, effectively "syncing" them. [See this for more](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).

Comment: Oh gotcha. Let me give this a try

Comment: So I got the prop going from my `routes.js` file to my `Login.js` successfully working I can change the `isAuthenticated` state in `routes` and see it console.logged in the login page. Now, I will handle the setting of the state all in the routes

Comment: I have a function `handleSubmit` in the `Login.js` which will send the filled out form fields to my server and verify that it is a proper login. After I get a response from the server, where would I go about setting the `isAuthenticated` state? The response will reside in the `Login.js` component but `isAuthenticated` is handled in `routes.js`

Comment: You would call `setAuthenticated` which is also passed as a prop. Just do `this.props.setAuthenticated(true)` from Login.